# How to properly use firebase in js, without exposing database to users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase with firebase hosting (node js backend) to let logged-in users upload a file.

I let users log in using email and password. The file should be uploaded to firebase storage with its details (provided by the user through a form) to be stored in firebase database.

I am successful in doing this using firebase in js(client-side).

However, with firebase at the client side, anyone can write any javascript code to do anything with firebase db, storage, and even they can create a new users directly which is very bad.

My DB security rule:

```
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
```

I couldn't find any helpful content regarding this. Even in the official sample code by Google (for js) is implemented in a similar way.

So, how should I **properly** use firebase in js without the above problems or should I even use it?
Should I shift everything to node.js backend? But then how do I get the file uploaded by the user in node js?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Correctly implement security rules for mobile and web clients directly accessing your database and storage.  There are security rules available for Realtime Database, Firestore, and Cloud Storage.
2. Move everything to a backend, where your client should pass along a Firebase Auth ID token with every request, validate it using the Firebase Admin SDK, and only perform the operation if that user is allowed, by whatever logic you choose.

It's up to you to decide which option is better for your specific use case.

Comment: If my javascript code can use database, then can't any js code in the console can also do the same, even with security?

Comment: No, security rules are implemented on the server.  You should read about them.

Comment: Thanx Doug, I have updated my question to include current security rules. Would u mind telling me correct security rules to solve my problem? Both the js codes are running in the same environment, so how will the server differentiate?

Comment: What you're asking is too broad.  You will have to translate your requirements for security into appropriate rules, just like writing code.  It's not just a matter of pasting the right code in there.